# Google Firebase - Polymerfire, getting a callback on the initial application initialization

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there anyway to do something like this with firebase.

```
var loaded = false;
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
app.then(function(user) {

  // initialization complete
  loaded = true;

  if(user){
    // user logged in
  } 
  else 
  {
     // user not logged in
  }
});
```

The above solution, if possible, would provide me with the knowledge that a user has or has not been logged in, as well as the information the application is attempting to get a user.

I can then only show the page to the user once I know that the page is not going to change in the next second.

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` should always be invoked with the current state when you attach it. If you're having problems with that, can you share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user